# How to connect "FPV Night Vision QVGA 320X240 Monocular" to raspberry 4?

Tags: hardware, display, pi-4, connection, modules

I am working on a project which need this module to be connected with raspberry pi 4 or 3. I tried some to convert into single RCA cable (worked) but I want to convert it into HDMI. I am unable to determine its connections and so can anyone help me connect this module to raspberry pi.

- FPV Night Vision QVGA 320X240 Monocular

[image: 1]]

- Wire Description
  [image: 2]]
- Single RCA cable

[image: 3]]

Comment: how is this related to the RPi?

Comment: Because i want to connect this module to rpi 3 or 4 ?

Comment: Video in to the inside of the av and negative to outside of av cable.